# Overlapping images

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to code a navigation using irregular (non-rectangle) buttons. The edges overlap each other on the Y axis so I'm not sure how to do this in HTML/CSS. I could use an imagemap but would rather not. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks! (I included the image link here):

[Sample Navigation Image](http://development.mediatavern.com/sample_nav.png)

Comment: What are the target browsers? Any old IEs?

Comment: The current browsers for FF, Safari and Chrome. IE9+ for IE.

Comment: Is this your wishlist or the on of your client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some options:

1. Use a single image with an image map
2. Use overlaid divs that have CSS rotate transforms applied. Add click handlers to these divs.
3. Use SVG shapes and apply links to them. I've added an example.

---

Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/Phu5x/

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<a xlink:href="/svg/index.html">
   <polygon points="15,10  95, 10  85, 30  5, 30"
        style="fill: red; stroke: black;"/>
 </a>
</svg>
```

Comment: For backward compatibility only the first alternative applies

Comment: @yunzen Evidently this is not required.

Comment: What evidence? There's no CSS-transform or SVG support in IE lte 8

Comment: @yunzen `The current browsers for FF, Safari and Chrome. IE9+ for IE` He just replied to you with this. Did you miss it?

Comment: 1. I commented on this before the question for the target browsers. 2. It's evidentially not backward compatible. Not regarding this special question but in general.

Comment: @yunzen Look at your second comment (the one that demands evidence for backward compatibility not being required). It occurs 11 minutes ago. His response to you (containing evidence that backward compatibility is not required) occurred 20 minutes ago.

Comment: Thank you both for your help and concern here. I'm going to try Asad's suggestion and possibly the PNG/Imagemap solution. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want mouse over effects, try a single transparent PNG image with an image map. Put the event handlers on the `<area>` elements, if you need support for older IEs.